# How can I design a Custom gateway for wifi

Tags: dns, php, gateway, qos

I once logged-in to my router (192.168.1.1) and noticed that alot of my neighbors are connected to it, probably more than 16 different IPs/MAC adresses are stored in my DHCP logs.

After I have setup a password to secure my Wifi connexion, I realized I was the only free Wifi spot for all my neighbors in my appartement.

So I got this idea of making an other free wifi spot, with no internet access, but I want to make it so when users are connected, and  navigates to any url (say like google.com) I want them to be redirected to a Webserver on my local network (for example:  192.168.1.25) that will show a webpage I made in PHP, so they can chat, or exchange files, etc.

I also want to add a password input in my PHP webpage; If the user inputs the right password, it will allow him to access my internet for like 2 or 3 hours, if he doesn't exceed a certain bandwidth limit.

To make this, I **think** I need:

1) A DNS server that can redirect any domaine (*) to one specific IP.

2) A Gateway software, or API that can allow me to control who's using my internet, with maybe some easy QoS settings ?

I have two simple D-Link Wifi routers, but I also have a USB Wifi (Access Point capable mode) that I can use directly as a network card without the router if I have to.

Anyways, does anyone have any idea how I can do this ? Is it possible ? What should I write in google to find a Gateway, API, or something that can help me build this using PHP or any other program langage ?
Anyone knows a DNS server that can do the job ? And a QoS or Gateway that I can controle using PHP Or any other program langage? Please help with anything you have. (Ans sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say you want to mess with your neighbours, but the body of your question says you actually want to help them. I've edited your headline to what I think you actually want to do.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Don't pay attention to the title, it's just a way of saying: "surprise my neighbours". But thank's for your comment!

Comment: I didn't want you title to misrepresent your intentions. You can change it back:-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you had a dd-wrt firmware on your router you can have it on a seperate WLAN (as a guest network) and there are several option for wireless security: WPA,WEP,RADIUS, etc. 
You can choose RADIUS server for wireless authentication and then point the IP of the "Radius Server' to the server for authentication.

Comment: It seems like a good idea, but my D-LINK routers aren't dd-wrt compatible. I'll have to get some linksys routers if I don't find any other solution :) Thank you.